# appJar - How to check if entry box is empty

Tags: python

I'm making a consumption checking program with appJar(Python) and i want to know how do you check if an entry box is empty

```
def press(name):
   jan = win.getEntry("Jan")
   if(jan == ""):
       jan == 0
   else:
       jan = int(win.getEntry("Jan"))
win.addLabelEntry("Jan")
win.addButton("Confirm", press)
```

This constantly gives me errors like ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Thanks!

Comment: What is the value of `win.getEntry("Jan")`?

Comment: its an int for examle 500

Comment: apparently, it's not always what you expect. The error (as you've pasted it) is literally telling you that you tried to convert an empty str to an int, which is obviously not possible.

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in your assignment.
When you check if the variable is empty, you don't set it to 0.
Instead, you are doing a comparison.

Replace: `jan == 0`
With: `jan = 0`